# Slick Grid - Select all rows for processing Issue

Tags: javascript, checkbox, slickgrid, selectall

I am facing the issue with slick grid when I select all the rows on the grid and submit the data for save.
The data is processed in the backend properly but the columns which gets updated based on processing status does not get refreshed with the updated status when the grid renders back.
This happens only when I select all the rows on the grid and process the data.
What do you think could cause the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Once you get response from the AJAX call and once the items are set in the dataView, add the below lines of code for the latest changes to be reflected in the grid:

```
dataView.beginUpdate();                 
dataView.setItems(items); // data from response
dataView.endUpdate();
// Below 2 lines are important
grid.updateRowCount();
grid.invalidateRows(selectedrows);
grid.render();
```

Hope this works